# 4 images in a line without creating a horizontal scroll bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project (that uses HTML and CSS) where I need to have 4 images in a line that scale up and down depending on the width of the user's screen so it does not create any x overlay.

I have tried using `white-space: nowrap;` but that just adds a horizontal scroll bar which I don't want.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `width: 25vw;`?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp 

use width 25% or like @NiettheDarkAbsol suggested width: 25vw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex is the best way to achieve this.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: space-between;
}

.item-0 {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item-0">a</div>
    <div class="item-1">b</div>
    <div class="item-2">c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}    

.container > div {
width: 25%;
}

<div class="container">
<div>
<img style="height:auto; width:100%" src"">
</div>
<div>
<img style="height:auto; width:100%" src"">
</div>
<div>
<img style="height:auto; width:100%" src"">
</div>
<div>
<img style="height:auto; width:100%" src"">
</div>
</div>
```